# Variable changes when pass from javascript to php

Tags: javascript, php

so i have this code

```
 $('#sepia').click(function () {
    var filePathName = tempFilePath;
    alert(filePathName);
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'php/sepia.php',
        data: {
            FilePath: filePathName
        },
        success: function (data) {
            pictureReset();
        }
    });
});
```

alert(filePathName) has the correct value test.jpg but as soon as its passed with

```
            data: {
                FilePath: filePathName
            }
```

the value is changes to incomprehensible text like this `jhSerZR6i1T952C3bk7vEOGCj8Pz_tBYtuHcgrgj81A.`

even if i replace `filePathName` with 'hp_2.jpg`  i still get the same random letter message

never mind found the error. wasn't anywhere near that bit of code but when i came back to the script to use the file path name. added +"" at the end and fixed it :)

Comment: First guess? You have a reference to an /image/.  Your `alert` statement is stringifying it, turning it into just a file name, but the `POST` is actually upload the image iself.

Comment: so if i passed FilePath: filePathName+'' would it fix it?

Comment: If my guess is right, it should.  You could add a `console.log(filePathName)` right before your `alert` and see what it gives you.

Comment: it returns the correct filepath name as well, i added the '' and i still get that long string :(

Comment: OK.. second try: Look at your debugging tools `Network` tab and see what is actually being sent.  If the string `test.jpg` is being sent, then the problem has to be on the server-side PHP code.

Comment: btw something i missed that might be important is that it works fine on localhost

Comment: on the network tab it tries to pass the jhSerZR6i1T952C3bk7vEOGCj8Pz_tBYtuHcgrgj81A ?string? but says not found

Comment: have you tried to set the datatype ? dataType: "text" guess it was text... or html ?!?!? some like this...

Comment: if add the quotes in the end it should/does make it to string. and i still get that scrambled variable

Comment: is this a yes or a no on my question? when my wife says honey, i know she means me but i still have a name and she could mean some to put on her bread. if you understand what i mean :D

Comment: lol, its a no, but it doesn't matter since i put the quotes right?

Comment: never know :) sometimes it matters if you say array or Array. in php no problem, in js it is one. add a .done(function(response){console.log(response);}) and add a print_r($_POST); in php and check your console whats posted

Comment: before i do these changes, it works on my localhost exactly like this. does your theory still stand with this information?

Comment: What exactly is `tempFilePath` ?? (FileObject, StringObject,...)

Comment: just duplicate your files and try what i posted in the question answere.. just want to see whats the result

Comment: prints `Array([FilePath] => HP_2.jpg)`

Comment: `Array([FilePath] => HP_2.jpg` is that what you want... isn't it ?

Comment: yes :D edited: so how do i get that string instead!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, lets try some else....

usual it's the same but it may gives a other result...

```
var tempFilePath = 'test.jpg';
$('#sepia').click(function () {
    var filePathName = tempFilePath;
    $.post('php/sepia.php', 
    {
        data:   {
                    //FilePath: filePathName changed to
                    fpath: filePathName
                }
    }).done(function(response){
        console.log(response);
    });
});
```

and add this to sepia.php:

```
<?php
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($_POST);
    echo "</pre>";
    die();

    // rest of your code
?>
```

this should return

```
array( 
       "FilePath" => "test.jpg" 
);
```

in the console

Comment: returns the incomprehensible string as well

Comment: just for try and error... change  `FilePath` to `fpath`